# How to enable autocomplete on each key event in ace editor?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor, autosuggest

I am able to get the autocompletion list on (ctrl+space) key event in ace editor but I want to achieve the same behavior on user key event. Is there any way to do the same?

Answer (score 2):

For adding custom autocomplete you need to bind the key, with **addCommand**, and then call the auto-complete

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
        name: "myCommand",
        bindKey: { win: "$", mac: "$" },
        exec: function (editor) {
              autocomplete();
        }
 });
```

Once the user trigger's the key you can call your autocomplete function, I'm adding a sample autocomplete function here, make the changes as you require.

```
autocomplete: function () {
        staticWordCompleter = {
            var getWordList = function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback, isRHSEditor) {
            var wordList = ["Java","Javascript","Python"]; // add your words to this list

            callback(null, wordList.map(function(word) {
            return {
                 caption: word,
                value: word
            };
   }));
  editor.completers = [staticWordCompleter];
}
```

To always use autocomplete you can try this:

```
editor.commands.on("afterExec", function (e) {
    if (e.command.name == "insertstring" && /^[\w.]$/.test(e.args)) {
        editor.execCommand("startAutocomplete");
    }
});
```

Or you can bind the change event and call the autocomplete, which would trigger the autocomplete on each click

```
editor.on("change", function () {
      autocomplete();
});
```

Comment: This will work once user press "$" key. I want it to enable it for each and every key.

Comment: @ranjeetkumar can you also try the new method, I added to the answer. You can use the on change event